# Upload a file to specific folderid using REST Api

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I've searched all documents in google drive api and I can't able to find how to upload a file to folderid using REST APi. Can anyone please help me on this?

```
   public void UploadFiletoDrive()
    {
        var gmodel = GetAccessToken();
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/?uploadType=media");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + gmodel.access_token;
        request.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        FileStream filestream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Developer\Downloads\unnamed (2).jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = filestream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            dataStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        filestream.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Search again. It's there. folder==parent

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've missed the [Work with Folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder) docs.

Inserting a file in a folder using Java:

```
String folderId = "0BwwA4oUTeiV1TGRPeTVjaWRDY1E";
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("photo.jpg");
fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(folderId));
java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("files/photo.jpg");
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", filePath);
File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
        .setFields("id, parents")
        .execute();
System.out.println("File ID: " + file.getId());
```

Implementation for other languages are also included like PHP, Python, NodeJS.

Also, check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903106/upload-files-to-specified-folder-in-google-drive) for additional reference.

```
body.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(folderId)));
```

Comment: I've already seen these code in docs, please look at my question once again..am asking using REST APi...not with JAVA or  .Net

Comment: please check the code above, am able to insert any file to drive root folder but not to specific folder.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code is doing a media upload, ie. no metadata, You should be using a multipart upload so you can specify both metadata such as parent folder id and content.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading a file to google drive using REST API has following steps.

- Get parent folderID using list API
- Create file with parent="folder ID" using create api and get "fileId" in response
- upload file to "fileId

Following is javascript code to upload file using REST API

```
const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/' + fileId + '?uploadType=media';
if(self.fetch){
        // console.log("Fetch found, Using fetch");
        var setHeaders = new Headers();
        setHeaders.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + authToken.access_token);
        setHeaders.append('Content-Type', mime);
        var setOptions = {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: setHeaders,
        body: blob
        };
        fetch(url,setOptions)
        .then(response => { if(response.ok){
            // console.log("save to google using fetch");
        }
                    else{
                    // console.log("Response wast not ok");
                    }
                  })
        .catch(error => {
        // console.log("There is an error " + error.message);
        });
        }
```